# Several JScrollPanes in JList

Tags: java, scroll, jscrollpane, jlist

I have got a JList in which several JPanels with a JScrollPane are placed:
[JList with JPanels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COMS7.png)

Now my problem is, that I am not able to scroll the inner placed JScrollPanes. Only the one holding the Jlist is scrollable.

It would be nice to be able to scroll the inner ones when the JPanel is selected, otherwise the outter JScrollPane should be "enabled".

Here's what I've got so far:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane;

public TestScrollPane() {
    initComponents();

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane();

    DefaultListModel lm1 = new DefaultListModel();
    Object[] firstPages = new Object[]{getPanel(), getPanel(), getPanel(), getPanel(), getPanel(), getPanel(), getPanel(), getPanel(), getPanel(), getPanel()};
    for (Object o : firstPages) {
        lm1.addElement(o);
    }

    final JList list = new JList(lm1);

    list.setVisibleRowCount(1);
    list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);
    list.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

    list.setCellRenderer(new ListCellRenderer() {
        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            return (JPanel) value;
        }
    });

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);

    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public JPanel getPanel() {
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    initComponents();
    String set = "test\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\n";
    JTextPane text = new JTextPane();
    text.setText(set);

    JScrollPane scr = new JScrollPane(text);

    scr.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

    p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(scr, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 120));
    p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));

    return p;
}
```

How do I do that? 
Thanks.

Comment: Don't use a JList. A renderer is not a real component so it doesn't respond to events. Maybe use a BoxLayout to display the panels. Or maybe you can use a single column JTable. Table's support editors which are real components. So when you select a row you could places that row in editing mode. You would need a custom editor to use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a moderately good solution for my problem:

```
list.setSelectionModel(new DefaultListSelectionModel() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void setSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1) {
            if (index0 == index1) {
                if (index0 != 0 && index0 != list.getModel().getSize() - 1) {
                    if (!isSelectedIndex(index0)) {
                        final int finalIndex0 = index0;
                        list.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
                                JPanel p = (JPanel) list.getModel().getElementAt(finalIndex0);
                                ((JScrollPane) p.getComponent(0)).getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(((JScrollPane) p.getComponent(0)).getVerticalScrollBar().getValue() - e.getWheelRotation());

                                repaint();

                                p.validate();
                                p.repaint();
                            }
                        });

                        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
                        super.setSelectionInterval(index0, index1);
                    } else {
                        try {
                            MouseWheelListener[] mwls = list.getMouseWheelListeners();
                            for (int i = 0; i < mwls.length; i++) {
                                list.removeMouseWheelListener(mwls[i]);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception x) {
                        }

                        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
                        super.removeSelectionInterval(index0, index1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

With this selection model I am able to scroll my selected JPanel(JScrollPanes). But I am still not able to scroll with my mouse.

So if anyone got a better solution, it would be nice to hear about it.

Thanks.